# Angular 5 - Forcing users to get new version of application

Tags: angular, caching

I have an Angular 5 application which is deployed to Azure using ng build --prod

I want the user to be forced to take a new version of the application every time it is released including any updates to style sheets.

However I am finding that often we need to use Ctrl F5 or Shift F5 on the browser to get the updated application down.

Is there a standard approach in Angular to forcing an update?

Comment: Which version of the angular-cli are you using? Cache-busting is on by default for prod builds in 6.x versions.

Comment: It uses Angular 5 i.e Angular CLI 1.x

Answer (score 1):

If you build Angular application using 'ng build --prod'. Angular add unique hash names to the bundler script files. So on new deployment  browser will refetch the latest bundler files.